# How to build a model with multiple target variables or rather multi labels where output probabilities add to 1

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to build a classification model, where each user/customer has probability of affinity to do 3 actions. Take an example, where customer can listen to 3 genres of something (say music). I want an output like this:

customer_id|propensity for Pop|propensity for EDM|[ropensity for Classical

C1|0.8|0.2|0.1

C2|0.92|0.08|0.0

How do I go about doing this? I googled the difference between multi class and multi label classification.
Looks like multi-class is not the way to go , since in my input/training, a person can have listened to more than 1 genre, so I cannot classify a customer as pop only, or EDM only.

How do I build my training set?

My input variables are time spent on each genre, days spent on each genre, completion rate of each genre. My labels for training (each customer will have 3 labels), would be basically, if a user streamed Pop only in next 28 days, then Pop = 1 . If a user listened to both Pop and EDM, then Pop=1 EDM=1.

I want the final probabilities to add up to 1.

Any help will be appreciated.